# Excluding lists

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking for most elegant and efficient way to exclude elements from one list which are existing in another. Let's say there is:

```
List<A> As which contains more than 1 000 000 records
List<B> Bs which contains more than 100 000 records
```

I need to remove all elements from list `As` where `As.Id` is equal `Bs.Id`. I just need to reduce As by elements from Bs containing same Id. Operations my repeat hundreds times. What is the most efficient (and elegant) way to solve that issue? I wish *LINQ* had `NotIn`.

```
foreach(a in As)
{
    if(Bs.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id)
        As.Remove(a);
}
```

Takes pretty long to complete.

Comment: Depending on the source of the lists, the most elegant and efficient solution may not even be linq - given the amount of data, are you loading it from somewhere else?  For example, if they are records from a database, you'd be much better off doing the work in the DB.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't opportunity to do it in database.

Comment: Is list `As` containing unique `A`s?

Comment: See msdn Except : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Personally, I'd use a dictionary and put the id as the key and the object as the value then have an if statement that check if the dictionary Contains(id) the remove.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that `A.Id` as well as `B.Id` are of type `int`, you can turn `List<B>` into `HashSet<int>` (*efficiency*) than use `RemoveAll` (is it supposed to be *elegant*?):

```
//TODO: I've assumed that Id is of type int, change HashSet<T> if required 
// Efficiency: HashSet.Contains has O(1) time complexity when List.Contains - O(n)
HashSet<int> IdsToExclude = new HashSet<int>(Bs
  .Select(b => b.Id)); // <- Linq (Select) is OK here...

// ... but not here (efficiency and if you don't mind, elegancy):
// We don't want Linq since Linq (Except) will create a new collection of about 1e6 items
// All we want is to modify the existing collection in place: RemoveAll
As.RemoveAll(a => IdsToExclude.Contains(a.Id));
```

Comment: Don't think `Except` can even work here as it can only work on the same type.

Comment: @stt106: Sure we can't put naive `As = As.Except(...).ToArray();` what I argue against is `As = As.Select(...).Except(...).ToArray();`: it's `ToArray()` that's the evil.

Answer (score 0):

Your original approach is too slow because it's O(n^3).
If you have to use `List` (which is not friendly for removing) and there are many items in it, in this case I think it's probably better to filter then reassign the list rather than filtering in-place as `Remove` or `RemoveAll` internally have to first filter then partially clear the backing array to remove elements.

If `As` contains unique Ids then converting it to a dictionary (or better start with a dictionary) is probably more efficient than filtering a list.

```
var As = new List<A> { new A { Id = 1 }, new A { Id = 2 }, new A { Id = 3 }, new A { Id = 4 } };
var Bs = new List<B> { new B { Id = 1 }, new B { Id = 2 } };
var set = new HashSet<int>(Bs.Select(b => b.Id));
var filtered = from a in As
               where !set.Contains(a.Id)
               select a;

// of course, only convert when it's used to get lazy evaluation benefit.
As = filtered.ToList();


// If As has unique Ids
var dictA = As.ToDictionary(a => a.Id, a => a);
foreach (var b in Bs)
{
   if (dictA.ContainsKey(b.Id))
        dictA.Remove(b.Id);
}

// either use dictA or if really have to convert back to a list
As = dictA.Values.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are inherited from the base that has id property:

```
class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
class A : Entity
{
    public string SomeProp { get; set; }
}
class B : Entity
{
    public string OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

you can create comparer:

```
class EntityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Entity>
{
    public bool Equals(Entity x, Entity y) => x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    public int GetHashCode(Entity obj) => base.GetHashCode();
}
```

and use Except method:

```
first.Except(second, new EntityComparer()).OfType<A>();
```

Else use Dmitry Bychenko method https://stackoverflow.com/a/44022567/6503504